# Is it possible to is VS Code Dev Containers with Windows-based containers?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VSCode dev containers support Dockerfiles where the base is a Windows Server Core base image? From looking at the docker build command, it seems that it assumes a Linux-based image.

Answer (score 2):

Based on official documentation from here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_remote-containers-limitations :

"Windows container images are **not** yet supported."